# Calling Monday.com API but getting JSON related error

Tags: google-apps-script

Running the code below gets me the error message: `Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 4`

I think the issue is that the data retrieved is not being parsed properly but I am a complete noob when it comes to Apps Scripts and APIs so would appreciate support here.

```
// Google Apps Script code

function syncMondayToSheets() {
    var mondayBoardId = '......';
  var googleSheetId = '.......';
  var sheetName = 'Sheet1';
  
  var mondayApiKey = '.......';
  
  var mondayUrl = 'https://api.monday.com/v2';
  var headers = { 'Authorization': mondayApiKey };
  var params = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(googleSheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var lastSyncedRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  
  // Retrieve items from Monday.com board
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(mondayUrl + '/boards/' + mondayBoardId + '/items', params);
  var responseData = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var items = responseData.data;

  var dataToSync = [];

  
  // Prepare data for syncing
  items.forEach(function(item) {
    var row = [];
    row.push(item.id);
    row.push(item.name);
    row.push(item.column_values[0].text);
    // Add more columns as needed
    
    dataToSync.push(row);
  });
  
  // Write data to Google Sheets
  var range = sheet.getRange(lastSyncedRow + 1, 1, dataToSync.length, dataToSync[0].length);
  range.setValues(dataToSync);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot know the error line from your question. From `Calling Monday.com API but getting JSON related error`, your error line is `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(mondayUrl + '/boards/' + mondayBoardId + '/items', params);`? For example, if your error of `Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 4` occurs at `var responseData = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());`, I think that knowing the value of `response.getContentText()` will help to think of the reason for the issue.

Comment: I get the error `"500 Internal Server Error
If you are the administrator of this website, then please read this web application's log file and/or the web server's log file to find out what went wrong."`. Based on the documentation, this suggests one of the two below:

-Invalid arguments, such as board or item IDs that don't exist
-Malformatted JSON column values when using the create_item or change_multiple_column_values mutations.

But not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About your reply, in your question, you say `Running the code below gets me the error message: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 4`. But, in your reply, you say `I get the error "500 Internal Server Error If you are the administrator of this website, then please read this web application's log file and/or the web server's log file to find out what went wrong."`. From this situation, I cannot understand your current situation. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue?